# Optimizing a memoization decorator to not increase call stack

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a very, very basic memoization decorator that I need to optimize below:

```
def memoize(function):
    memos = {}
    def wrapper(*args):
        try:
            return memos[args]
        except KeyError:
            pass
        result = function(*args)
        memos[args] = result
        return result
    return wrapper
```

The goal is to make this so that it doesn't add on to the call stack. It actually doubles it right now. I realize that I can embed this on a function by function basis, but that is not desired as I would like a global solution for memoizing. Any ideas?

Comment: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/498245-lru-and-lfu-cache-decorators/

Comment: @JakobBowyer, I am doing this for preparation for an upcoming programming competition. We can only bring in notes, so I need something so that is short to type, so I don't need something as robust.

Comment: This only adds one extra function call to the stack, which is twice as much as just calling the undecorated function, isn't really doubling the the size of the entire calls tack. The best a decorator can do is replace a function with itself and somehow not call the original function -- which I'm not sure is possible in any kind of general sense.

Comment: In Python 3.2, you can just use `import functools; @functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)`, which is even quicker to type and part of the standard library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Python 3.2, you can just use the standard library:

```
import functools

@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def doit(...):
    ...
```

It's easy to remember and part of the standard library.